# What is wrong with this python calculator program? (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator, python-3.4

The error reads as:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/JackPottage/Documents/PythonProjects/Calculator/Calculator.py", line 76, in equals
    while num1[g] is not "+" or "-" or "*" or "/":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

The code is:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack()
topframe=Frame(root)
topframe.pack()
s=1

def clear():
    txtDisplay.delete(0,END)
    return

def one():
    global s
    txtDisplay.insert(s,"1")
    s+=1
def two():
    global s
    txtDisplay.insert(s,"2")
    s+=1
def three():
    global s
    txtDisplay.insert(s,"3")
    s+=1
def four():
    global s
    txtDisplay.insert(s,"4")
    s+=1
def five():
    global s
    txtDisplay.insert(s,"5")
    s+=1
def six():
    global s
    txtDisplay.insert(s,"6")
    s+=1
def seven():
    global s 
    txtDisplay.insert(s,"7")
    s+=1
def eight():
    global s
    txtDisplay.insert(s,"8")
    s+=1
def nine():
    global s 
    txtDisplay.insert(s,"9")
    s+=1
def zero():
    global s
    txtDisplay.insert(s,"0")
    s+=1
def plus():
    global s 
    txtDisplay.insert(s,"+")
    s+=1
def minus():
    global s  
    txtDisplay.insert(s,"-")
    s+=1
def times():
    global s 
    txtDisplay.insert(s,"*")
    s+=1
def divide():
    global s 
    txtDisplay.insert(s,"/")
    s+=1
def equals():
    global num1
    print(num1)
    g=0
    number1=str("")
    while num1[g] is not "+" or "-" or "*" or "/":
        number1=str(number1)+str(num1[g])
        print(number1)
        g=+1




One= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="1", bg="green", command=one)
One.grid(row=1, column=0)
Two= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="2", bg="green", command=two)
Two.grid(row=1, column=1)
Three= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="3", bg="green", command=three)
Three.grid(row=1, column=2)
Four= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="4", bg="green", command=four)
Four.grid(row=2, column=0)
Five= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="5", bg="green", command=five)
Five.grid(row=2, column=1)
Six= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="6", bg="green", command=six)
Six.grid(row=2, column=2)
Seven= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="7", bg="green", command=seven)
Seven.grid(row=3, column=0)
Eight= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="8", bg="green", command=eight)
Eight.grid(row=3, column=1)
Nine= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="9", bg="green", command=nine)
Nine.grid(row=3, column=2)
Zero= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="0", bg="green", command=zero)
Zero.grid(row=4, column=0)
num1=""
txtDisplay=Entry(frame, textvariable=num1, insertwidth=1, font=30, bg="Dark Orange")
txtDisplay.grid(columnspan=3)
Equals= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="=", bg="green", command=equals)
Equals.grid(row=4, column=2)
Clear= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="C", bg="green", command=clear)
Clear.grid(row=4, column=1)
Plus= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="+", bg="green", command=plus)
Plus.grid(row=1, column=3)
Minus= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="-", bg="green", command=minus)
Minus.grid(row=2, column=3)
Times= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="*", bg="green", command=times)
Times.grid(row=3, column=3)
Divide= Button(topframe, bd=8, text="/", bg="green", command=divide)
Divide.grid(row=4, column=3)


root.mainloop()
```

My main question would be not only what errors exist in my code, but what is meant by: string index out of range.

Any help would be appreciated, as I am still rather new to programming.
Thanks in advance.

It is worth noting the program is by no means finished.

Comment: Not directly your error, but `num1[g] is not "+" or "-" or "*" or "/"` does not do what you think it does. See [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125)

Comment: Scratch that, that is the direct cause, because that `while` loop never ends.

Comment: Use `num1[g] in '+-*/'` instead.

Comment: Also worth noting: use `==` to compare strings, not `is` (which only tests identity, and it's not necessarily true that any two strings which both have `"a"` as the value are the same string.)

Answer (score 0):

The first time you initialize `num1`, it's set to `""` and never changes, therefore raising an error when trying to access the index 0.
But that's not the only problem, see Martijn's comments for more.